# Getting location in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cllocationmanager

I realize there are lots of other pages that attempt to solve the challenge of getting user location using `CLLocationManager()` in ios swift but they don't work for me which is why I created this question. My code is below which I believe correctly implements the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` but the call to `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` never calls the `locationManager` function. This makes the Google Map simply open to a random position. I've simulated certain locations in the scheme and they work great like South Africa

example of Google Map with simulated location: 
[image]

However, when I uncheck the simulation, the location is never found. Any advice or help would be appreciated. Not sure if this is a problem with my computer or code.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class Map: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate  {

    var mapView: GMSMapView?
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 40.7, longitude: -74.0, zoom: 4.0))
        view = mapView

        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()){
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locations.last!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: locations.last!.coordinate.longitude)

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude, zoom: 4.0);
        self.mapView?.camera = camera
        self.mapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        let marker = GMSMarker(position: center)

        print("Latitude :\(center.latitude)")
        print("Longitude :\(center.longitude)")

        marker.map = self.mapView
        marker.title = "Current Location"

        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you running on the simulator or an actual device?

Comment: You should instantiate your location manager as early as possible in the lifecycle of your app, like the app delegate (which is where I choose). From there, you can better control the flow of your UX. One avenue is to keep the user at bay (i.e. extended launch screen) until the location manager has a location; then when the user navigates to this view controller (in your question), there is guaranteed to be a location and the map won't render to a random coordinate. Remember, it takes time for the location manager to get a coordinate--it's not instant.

Comment: I'm running on the simulator and don't have capability to run on a device right now. Also I tried using locationManager.requestLocation() (in AppDelegate) and storing it in Local Data and then retrieving it in my map class but it always failed to get the location. My wifi is seamless and I checked to make sure my mac had location enable. I don't know what's causing the issue.

Comment: The simulator will never get your *actual location*. You can only simulate locations when using the simulator.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that. Has it always been this way because I haven't used Swift in a while and the last time I used it, I know I collected true user location?

Comment: Yes, it has always been this way

Comment: You can only get actual location on a real device